# How to make clotted cream in the instant pot without the yogurt function?

Tags: instant-pot, clotted-cream

I found a bunch of recipes to make clotted cream using the yogurt function (https://www.thatskinnychickcanbake.com/homemade-clotted-cream/), but I have a Duo Crisp, which does not have that function. It has sous vide, saute, pressure cook, and slow cook.

Is it possible to make using any of those?

Comment: ChatGPG is not a search engine, it produces answers that *sound* good, but are often completely and occasionally dangerously wrong. Do not trust anything ChatGPG says.

Comment: Lol, that's fair. I'm just including it because I couldn't find a good answer on google--all search results use the yogurt function or something else I don't have.

Comment: "instant pot yogurt without yogurt button" gives some results, no idea of the same method (basically wrapping a turned off IP that is at the correct temp in a blanket) can be used for clotted cream

Comment: I've also found that most slow cookers uncovered on the warm feature keep a big pot of water at just about 110, an instant pot on keep warm might behave similarly

Answer (score 5):

You don't make clotted cream in an instant pot without a yogurt function, which is why you are not getting any search results. Making clotted cream involves heating cream to a constant warm temperature until the cream clots, which is similar to making yogurt. The yogurt mode on an instant pot heats to that relatively low temperature. If it doesn't have that mode it's going to pressure cook the cream and you won't get the result you want.

The steps above are not only wrong but possibly could damage an instant pot or pressure cooker. There are few recipes that would call for 4 hours of pressure cooking, and with the amount of water called for in these steps after 4 hours the cooker is likely to run dry,  which is **not** a good thing. ChatGPG pulled generic instructions for an instant pot, then the time it takes for some other methods to make clotted cream and mashed them together to give you something not only wrong but possibly dangerous.

Don't trust anything ChatGPG or any other AI chat tool says, they are clever but not designed for accuracy!

Comment: I do pressure cook for 4 hours - but that’s bone broth and there’s absolutely no risk of the pot running dry. Apart from that, that use case is probably rare.

Answer (score 0):

I've made clotted cream in my "instant pot" 3 times so far. I'll be doing it again in the next few weeks for x-mas. There is no yogurt button on my pot. I use the saute function which comes to a boil rather quickly. Then follow the rest of the instructions. My family fights over the leftovers and at least 3 of us has had clotted cream in the UK. Just make sure you are not using ultra pasteurized heavy cream.

Comment: Welcome Cathy! Would you be so kind and add more details about what you summarize as “the rest of the instructions”? I’m sure other users would appreciate the chance to learn more about how to make clotted cream like you do. You can always [edit] you answer with more details. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome Cathy! I agree with the comment above—could you outline step by step how you make it?